# Array.map logging but not showing on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have populated an array in my state object, called `plateHistory`.

Once the array has been populated, I was hoping my UI would update with the data I expect. However, the code below isn't giving me expected results.

The console.log logs the lines as expected, but it `<span>` never renders. I am trying to map through the array, which is working, as the `console.log` is logging - but why is the `<span>` never rendering? I think I am making a basic error, but can't seem to spot it.

Note that the line `this.state.plateHistory.length` goes from 'Nope', to the correct length. So that is working and the state object is being updated.

```
<p>Recently printed plates</p>
                <p>{this.state.plateHistory.length > 0 ? this.state.plateHistory[0].id : 'Nope'}</p>
                    {this.state.plateHistory.map((item, i) => {
                        <div>
                            <span>{item.id}</span>
                            <div className="col-lg-6 text-center" style={divStyle}>
                                <span>{item.id}</span>
                                {console.log(item.id)}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        })
                    }
```

Comment: Did you forget to `return` from the map callback?

Comment: Oh my! 2 hours I've been fighting with this, and you get it in 34 seconds! :) It was indeed the missing return! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hassan stated; the function you pass to map is not returning.

If you use arrow function with brackets you need to use the return statement:

```
x=>{return x+1}
```

If you don't use brackets than you get one statement and the result of that statement is the return value of the function:

```
x=>x+1;
```

If you want to return an object literal in one statement you have to use parenthesis as to not confuse the brackets for the object literal with brackets for function body:

```
x=>({xValue:x});
```

In your case you can try removing the brackets:

```
{
  this.state.plateHistory.map((item, i) =>//bracket removed
    <div>
      <span>{item.id}</span>
      <div className="col-lg-6 text-center" style={divStyle}>
        <span>{item.id}</span>
        {console.log(item.id)}
      </div>
    </div>
  /**closing bracket removed */)
}
```